# Javascript Radio Button Count and Calculation for Questionnaire

Tags: javascript, math, xhtml, forms

I am trying to create a simple questionnaire for a website but am fairly new to javascript and html

I do have a basic function to calculate a percentage and have created the html form with radio buttons and a submit button

There will be about 20 questions in the questionnaire which will have yes/no radio buttons.

What I need to do is have a way of looking at each question to see if the user answered yes or no.

If they answered yes then I need to keep total to then work out how many questions they answered yes too.

After the user has pressed the submit button I then need to display a summary based on the yes answer percentage calculated above

The summary may look like the following:
- To 33% and below you have ticked yes this mean THIS
- To 66% and below you have ticked yes this mean SOMETHING ELSE

`function CalculatePercentage() {
 a = document.form1.c.value;
 b = 10;
 c = a/b;
 d = c*100;
 document.form1.total2.value = d
 }`

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to find out if a radio button question answer is yes or not and then how to create the summary based on the percentage?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to calculate all the radio button values

```
Question1 <input type="radio" name="questions1" value="1" />Yes<br />
 <input type="radio" name="questions1" value="0" />No
Question2 <input type="radio" name="questions2" value="1" />Yes<br />
 <input type="radio" name="questions2" value="0" />No
```

JavaScript:

```
totalVal = 0;

// calculate the total number of yes clicked

for(y=0; y=noOfQuestion; y++)
{
    var questionNo = document.getElementsByName("questions" + y);
    for (i=0; i<questionNo.length; i++)
    {
      if (document.myform.questions[i].checked==true)
      {
        totalVal = totalVal + parseInt(document.myform.questions[i].value,10);
      }
    }
}
```

//calculate percentage

```
perc = totalVal/noOfQuestion;
perc = perc * 100;
percString = perc + "%";
```

to be continued

Comment: Hi, I've tried to implement your example but as the name on the radio buttons is the same they are mutually exclusive and remove the selection previously made.

Comment: try the solution now and see if its works and if not i will edit it again

Comment: i think your for loop is broken, no closing brace. (Ps thank u so far!)

Comment: should for (i=0; i<questionNo.length; i++) be removed?
document.myform.questions[i].checked is always null i think it should be questionNo which is the radio button but then questionNo.checked is also null too

Comment: I can work with the original version using check boxes that not a problem. marked this as the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using :

```
document.myform.questionNo[i]
```

You use simply :

```
questionNo[i]...
```

I did that and I got the answer.